# Outlook VBA - Scroll Folder View to Active Folder

Tags: vba, outlook

In VBA code, how can you scroll the Inbox folder to the Active Folder?  I'm setting the active folder in VBA code but then would like the window to scroll.

```
#fff is a folder object
Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = fff  '<-works
Set v = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView 
v.() '<-how can i scroll here?
```

This SO sounds perfect (!) but for some reason it was removed from SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53681568/outlook-vba-how-to-scroll-a-folder-into-view-on-the-sidebar

Comment: [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXJQ1.png) the deleted linked post, for <10K rep users - the question has no answers.

Comment: Thx @Mathieu.  Gives me less hope that someone will know the answer here..